# How to use "systemd --user" instance?

Tags: 15.04, dbus, systemd, systemd-logind

I have an executable I'd like to run as a user and that user should be able to start and stop that service without sudo.

I have `systemd --user` always running for the user by running `loginctl enable-linger user`

I've confirmed the `systemd --user` instance is running as that user using `ps` but when I try to run any `systemctl` command as that user, I get the following error:

```
vagrant-ubuntu-vivid-64:~$ systemctl --user list-units
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Connection refused
```

Based on my googling it sounds like I should have a `dbus-daemon` instance running as that user but it is not. It should be noted I'm switching to the user with `su` so it may not be counting as a "login".

I have two questions:

1. Can my user instance of `systemd` just use the system instance of d-bus?
2. Should Ubuntu somehow be starting a user instance of d-bus for me?

Comment: Ubuntu still uses upstart to manage the user session instead of a systemd user session.

Comment: @psusi thanks for the comment. Do you have a reference or some more docs on this?

Comment: Nope; just looked at the running system.

Comment: Confirmed you are correct with devs in irc. Systemd user sessions are blocked on Ubuntu phone moving to systemd. They recommended policykit instead. You can post your answer so I can mark this done if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu is still using `upstart` to manage the user session, and `systemd` only manages the system session.  Hopefully in the next release, the user session will migrate to `systemd`, and then this will work.

Comment: So there is no systemd user session D-Bus in Ubuntu? Is this also true for Kubuntu 15.10?

Comment: @Silicomancer, yes.

Comment: I tried a lot of things. And "systemctl --user list-units" acutally works on my system. Also "busctl --user | grep systemd" lists "org.freedesktop.systemd1" as "(activateable)". Doesn't this mean there is a user d-bus instance running?

Comment: @Silicomancer there is a user dbus session, but if you follow the chain of parent processes with `ps l` you will find that all of your processes are ancestors of an upstart process rather than a systemd one.  I'm not sure why `systemctl --user list-units` works... it seems that it shouldn't.

Comment: Ok. I see.  Thanks! Do you have an idea in which Kubuntu version that will change?

Comment: @Silicomancer, hopefully 16.04

Comment: Where does Ubuntu track this change? Is there a mailing list or launchpad entry for this?